# MPMediaItem file size increase when i export Music file using AVAssetExportSession

Tags: iphone, objective-c, mpmediaitem, avassetexportsession

My app have below functionality.

- Pick the music file from the `Music Library
- Upload that `MPMediaItem` (music file) to Server.

I am done with the above functionality But i have notice the one issue. i am export `MPMedeaItem` using [this link](https://stackoverflow.com/a/17206723/935381) and its working fine. When i convert `MPMediaItem` to `NSData` than check the size using `NSLog(@"Actual Size : %f KB", (CGFloat)data.length / (CGFloat)1024);`. **The actual file size is 2MB and i am getting the 4MB.**

So What may be the issue ?? It may be the reason to export in `AVAssetExportPresetAppleM4A` ?

`

Comment: AVAssetExportPresetAppleM4A may change the format of the input file if your inout file is mp3 the output will be m4a and the sizes differ